# For /f batch loop fails with error ") was unexpected at this time."

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

I'm writing what I thought would be a simple batch which will cycle through a .txt input file via a "FOR /F" to check a number of PC's for 3 file locations which will determine the OS or App version, Set a couple of Variable then rename a file and copy a new file in it's place..But I can't get it to work.
The batch fails with ) was unexpected at this time

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Here's the batch content

```
CD /D "C:\Win32app\Scripts\SEPXML"
FOR /f "Tokens=1" %%a IN (List.txt) DO (
    Echo %%a
    If exist "\\%%a\c$\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\CurrentVersion\Data\Config\SyLink.xml" (GoTo :Win2k3) else (GoTo :Next1)
    :Next1
    If exist "\\%%a\c$\Win32app\Symantec\SEPP\SyLink.xml" (GoTo :x86Serv) else (GoTo :Next2)
    :Next2
    If exist "\\%%a\c$\ProgramData\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\CurrentVersion\Data\Config\sylink.xml" (GoTo :Win2K8) else (GoTo :WriteError)

    :Win2k3
    Set SyLinkPath="\\%%a\c$\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\CurrentVersion\Data\Config"
    Set OSVer=Win2k3
    GoTo :Run

    :x86Serv
    Set SyLinkPath="\\%%a\c$\Win32app\Symantec\SEPP"
    Set OSVer=Win2k3OLD
    GoTo :Run

    :Win2K8
    Set SyLinkPath="\\%%a\c$\ProgramData\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\CurrentVersion\Data\Config"
    Set OSVer=Win2k8
    GoTo Run

    :Run
    Ren %SyLinkPath%\SyLink.xml %SyLinkPath%\SyLink.old
    Robocopy C:\Win32app\Scripts\SEPXML\SyLink %SyLinkPath% /r:0 /W:0 /copyall /Tee /Log+:C:\Win32app\Scripts\SEPXML\Log\Results.txt
    GoTo End

    :WriteError 
    Echo %%a >>C:\Win32app\Scripts\SEPXML\Log\Error-Servers.txt
    :End
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not everything needs to be enclosed in parenthesis, but there is a bigger problem.

Every time a `goto` is executed inside a `for` loop, all the looping is cancelled. You can not jump inside a block of code.

You can move the processing to a label to call or restructure the code to avoid the jump operations

```
CD /D "C:\Win32app\Scripts\SEPXML"

for /f "tokens=1" %%a in (List.txt) do (
    set "done="
    for %%b in (
        "\\%%a\c$\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\CurrentVersion\Data\Config"
        "\\%%a\c$\Win32app\Symantec\SEPP"
        "\\%%a\c$\ProgramData\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\CurrentVersion\Data\Config"
    ) do if not defined done if exist "%%~b\sylink.xml" (
        set "done=1"
        Ren "%%~b\SyLink.xml" "SyLink.old"
        Robocopy C:\Win32app\Scripts\SEP-XMLChange\SyLink "%%~b" /r:0 /W:0 /copyall /Tee /Log+:C:\Win32app\Scripts\SEP-XMLChange\Log\Results.txt
    )
    if not defined done (
        Echo %%a >>C:\Win32app\Scripts\SEP-XMLChange\Log\Error-Servers.txt
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response MC ND. I'm sorry I have to ask a likely silly question but where is the %%b variable coming from. I have tested your above code but receive an error "%b\sylink.xml" was unexpected at this time.
C:\Win32app\Scripts\SEPXML>    ) do if not defined done if exists "%b\sylink.xml
" (

Comment: @mark, Sorry, my fault. The `%%b` is assigned in the inner for loop with the `%%a` concatenated to the paths. The error happens because i typed `if exists` instead of `if exist`. Now the `s` is removed in code.

Comment: @mark, and there is an aditional error. As `%%b` is iterating over a list of quoted strings, all references should be `%%~b` to remove the quotes. Also corrected in code

Comment: Thank you. I must admit I don't entirely understand how this code operates and therefore your scripting abilities put mine to shame.. I must say I've very impressed it works a treat. Thank you once more MC ND. I'm grateful that you have taken the time to assist me.